# Some solution for developing website from multiple servers?

Tags: php, node.js, mongodb, scalability, developer-tools

Hi i want to build website from different server at same time... Servers must provide nginx, php, mongoDB, redis/memcacheD, nodeJS... I need minimum 5 servers... Buying 5 dedicated servers only for developing will be super expensive for me. Do you know any softwares or services providing these things ? And this is my schema [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXFjJ.png)

Comment: and why do you need 5 servers?

Comment: Hi, I do this kind of thing at work.  Each product gets it's own filesystem, user, port, ...  So each component can live with another one on the same system without interference from the other products.  Even better look at docker, this is the way to go, each component can be deployed as you require.

Comment: @Nic And how you developing your website?

Comment: It is a rather large corporation, so we have unix admins that setup servers, middleware (like me) that setup the different software products, and web developers that do the HTML-Java-JavaScript, ...  For my personal projects I do all 3 roles and use HTML, JS, JQuery, PHP.

Answer (score 0):

For developing you can install all them in your own computer. Unless its an small/obsolete PC your are going to have no problem. Other option can be use docker-compose for have a 'virtual' infraestructure but requires spent few days in understand it.